# Regex: check if encapsulated string is numeric

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a #hashtag parser in regex. I'm trying to make one identical to twitter's hashtag parser, but i couldn't find one identical on the internet, so i'm creating my own.

Here is an example of the desired outputs on a given inputs.

```
#inktober -> Valid hashtag.
#inktober2019 -> Valid hashtag.
#2019 -> Not a valid hashtag.
```

I'm stuck on detecting when a hashtag only contains numbers, which shouldn't be detected as hashtags.

Here is a link where i'm working on this regular expression:

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/tTB#tab-preg-match-all

I'm very inexperient in regex, so sorry if it is a stupid question.

My language is PHP.

Thank you! n.n

Comment: Don't forget hashtags with accented letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe,

```
(?i)#[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?=\s|$)
```

would simply work OK.

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?i)#[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?=\s|$)/m';
$str = '#inktober #inktober2019 #i #i1 #1 #2019
# inktober #@inktober2019 #@i #i1@ #1 #2019';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/X3Lr52/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/X3Lr52/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

---

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the extra links too. As i'm a newbie in regular expressions, I didn't know there was a regular expression visualizer.